# Why is my XAML Code not running?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

my C# Code works, but the XAML Code isn't working... I don't know what mistake I make. I'm a newbie on XAML and I try to learn it. When I delete this code:

> KeyDown = "HandleKeyDown"
>
> Initialized = "MainWindow_Initilized" Background ="DimGray">

then there is no error.

```
<Window x:Class="Tetris.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="570" Width="525">
    KeyDown = "HandleKeyDown" 
    Initialized = "MainWindow_Initilized" Background ="DimGray">

  <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="127">
      <Label Content="Label" Height="56" Name="Scores" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" />
      <Label Content="Label" Height="56" Name="Lines" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Name="MainGrid" Height="500" Width="250">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
  </DockPanel>
 </Window>
```

Comment: But I need the Code for the Programm.

Comment: `Why is my XAML Code not running?` - because XAML is a declarative language, not an imperative one. XAML code doesn't "run". It gets read just as if it were data, and transformed into an object graph.

Comment: What exactly happens, and what do you expect to happen instead? Any exception? Compiler error? What's the precise message?

Comment: @ O.R Mapper a Compilor error , I want to programm Tetris on WPF and  this doesnt "run" (transformed into an object graph?)  at the moment. I dont know why, cant see my mistake(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have an extra `>` there right before you declare your `KeyDown` attribute.

Take note of there the color highlight stops

```
<Window x:Class="Tetris.MainWindow"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
    Title="MainWindow" Height="570" Width="525">  
    KeyDown = "HandleKeyDown"   
    Initialized = "MainWindow_Initilized" Background ="DimGray">
```

I don't think you intend for that to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Because you closed the Window tag twice:

```
Title="MainWindow" Height="570" Width="525">
KeyDown = "HandleKeyDown" 
Initialized = "MainWindow_Initilized" Background ="DimGray">
```

You closed it after `Width="525"` and again after `Background ="DimGray"`. Remove the one after `Width="525"` and it should be fine provided that you have `</Window>` at the very bottom of your Window XAML.

Also, if you are trying to use `KeyDown` to implement keyboard shortcuts, you should be doing something like this instead:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+O" Command="{commands:ApplicationCommand}" CommandParameter="OpenFile"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: ohhhh dammn---- This happens all the time! Thank you :) Sorry I cant vote ur answer up at the moment, i will remember it later ;)